# jQuery function chaining with class based conditional, Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a block of jQ that swaps out some classes and adjusts the style of a button when triggered by the user.

It looks like this,

```
// Initial object selection
$(b)
    // Select the Icon
    .siblings('i')
    // add class of new icon
    .addClass('fa-check-square-o')
    // remove class of old icon
    .removeClass('fa-square-o')
    // select the parent element (label)
    .closest('label')
    // adjust for the size change of the icon
    .css('padding-right', '3px')
    // add the new button contextual class
    .addClass('btn-success')
    // remove possible old contexual button classes
    .removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning');
```

This works as expected, however, I have another case where a button might have a contextual `'btn-info'` class and I would like to determine if that class is present on the `'label'` element.

I thought I could do;

```
// ... jQ chain above ...
// remove possible old contextual button classes
.removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning')
// Conditonally check 'label' if it has class
.hasClass('btn-info')
// 'label' has the class... Do Stuff
.removeClass('btn-success btn-warning btn-danger');
```

But I get an error, "... removeClass() is not a function"

I also tried with `.has('.btn-info')` in place of `.hasClass()` and I don't get the error but I do not get the expected result of the other 3 classes being removed leaving the `'btn-info'` class.

Is this a logical workflow with chaining, do I have the right expectations or am I asking too much form jQ?

Thoughts much appreciated.

---

Html markup for good measure,

Just a simple bootstrap button group

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="ynna-yes" autocomplete="off">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg"></i>
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-danger">
         <input type="radio" name="options" id="ynna-no" autocomplete="off">
         <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-info">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="ynna-na" autocomplete="off">
          <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg"></i>
       </label>
   </div>
```

Comment: Obviously, there are some things that you can't do in a single line of code (chaining only). You will have to use the `.hasClass()` in a `if` condition and resume the chaining from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns a boolean so what you want to use is [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) which will return the matched elements.

```
.removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning')
.filter('.btn-info')
  .removeClass('btn-success btn-warning btn-danger');
```

Comment: so than after the closest they would reselect the button.... WIthout HTML Markup hard to help the OP

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) as it returns *boolean*, However it can be achieved   using [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

```
$(b)
    .closest('label:not(.btn-info)')
    .doSomething()
    .end()
    .closest('label.btn-info')
    .doSomething()
```

```js
$('li')
  .closest('.first')
  .css('color', 'red')
  .end()
  .closest('.second')
  .css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first">
  <li class="foo">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="bar">list item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
  <li class="foo">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="bar">list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a great thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `.hasClass()` call returns a boolean (`true` or `false`) so you can't chain on from it.

You can do this my filtering the element with `.filter()` and then applying your `removeClass()` to the filtered remains (which could be empty):

```
// remove possible old contextual button classes
.removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning')
// focus only on elements that have the btn-info class
.filter('.btn-info')
// remove classes from whatever is left
.removeClass('btn-success btn-warning btn-danger');
```

Answer (score 1):

If what I understand is right, then the below must help you:

```
$(b).removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning') ;
if ($(b).hasClass('btn-info')) {
    $(b).removeClass('btn-success btn-warning btn-danger') ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `.hasClass()` is a boolean (`true` or `false`) and no longer a jQuery object, therefore `.hasClass().removeClass()` is not a function.

You can either use the [`.filter()` function](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.hasClass()` as follows:

```
// ... jQ chain above ...
// remove possible old contextual button classes
.removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning')
// Conditonally check 'label' if it has class
.filter('.btn-info')
// 'label' has the class... Do Stuff
.removeClass('btn-success btn-warning btn-danger');
```

or use a conditional statement (like `if`), which unfortunately brakes the chain:

```
if(
// ... jQ chain above ...
// remove possible old contextual button classes
.removeClass('btn-danger btn-warning')
// Conditonally check 'label' if it has class
.hasClass('btn-info')
)
{
   // 'label' has the class... Do Stuff
   $(b).removeClass('btn-success btn-warning btn-danger');
}
```